# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest' after upgrading Android Studio to Electric Eel

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

After updating Android Studio to Electric Eel I cannot launch my application with following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @3c3bc30a
```

and this is return from flutter doctor

```
[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
```

Colleague of mine working on the same files, just on Visual Studio is not having any problem.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Clear and Invalidate Caches
[image]

Comment: It didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to download older version of Android Studio(last Dolphin version in my case).

After that everything worked like it used to it.